# style attribute expression value is not evaluated, yet src attribute is evaluated?

Tags: vue.js

What am I doing wrong here? (The literal object notation vs dot notation might not be relevant for my question. It's just me experimenting).

```
<template lang="pug">
- var medium_large = "obj.better_featured_image.media_details.sizes.medium_large.source_url";
- var literalMedium = "obj['better_featured_image']['media_details']['sizes']['medium']['source_url']"

#app
  div(v-for='(obj) in posts' :key='obj.index')

    // WORKS
    p {{obj.better_featured_image.id}}
    // out: 224

    // WORKS: - because of vue bind shorthand ":" :
    .feature(:src=literalMedium)
    .feature(:src=medium)
    // out: <div data-v-ab895722="" src="/app/uploads/2018/06/9f6c2fdb-de2a-3351-b105-bd158ea6c890-300x150.jpg" class="feature"></div>

    //ERROR  jshint: "unexpected token obj", (also tried without binding :style) atribute
    .feature(:style='background-image:url('+ {{obj.better_featured_image.source_url}} +');')
    .feature(:style='background-image:url('+ obj.better_featured_image.source_url +');')

</template>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function which returns a style object with background image property. Don't know how it plays with this pug you are using though.

```
<template>
  <div :style="createUrl(obj.source_url)"></div>
</template>

<script>
...
  methods: {
    createUrl: function(url) {
      return {
        'background-image': 'url(' + url + ')',
        width: '1000px',
        height: '1000px'
      }
    }
  },
}
</script>
```